Prove/disprove upper bound and lower bound of the Integral
Hey I need to Prove or disprove this sentence:
$$
\frac{4}{9}(e-1) \leq \int_0^1 \frac{e^x}{(1+x)(2-x)} \, dx \leq \frac{1}{2}(e-1)
$$
using the infimum and supremum method for integrals, where m and  M are the minimum and maximum values of the function over the interval [0,1], I showed the integral should be bounded as:
$$
0.5 \leq \int_0^1 \frac{e^x}{(1+x)(2-x)} \, dx \leq \frac{e}{2}
$$
therefore I thought that if I increase the lower bound and decrease the top bound this would be false, be in the answers it's say the sentence is true (maybe they are wrong?)
I hope if someone could help me with this.

Note that $(1+x)(2-x) \le 9/4$ and $(1+x)(2-x) \ge 2$ for $x \in[0, 1]$.

@openspace don't really understand how it helping me, it's already covered in what I did using the sentence to find minimum  and supremum

If $(1 + x)(2-x) \le 9/4$, then $\frac{1}{(1+x)(2-x)} \ge \frac{4}{9}$. Now you apply this bound and obtain the LHS.
